# CircleCI - Branch specific deployment not triggering deployment

Tags: git, google-app-engine, circleci

I am trying to have separate deployment targets via separate branches in my repository, and I want to use the circle.yml file to use the branch filtering feature. Here is my circle.yml file:

```
machine:
  environment:
    # Replace this with your project ID
    GCLOUD_PROJECT: "team4tress-165000"

    GCLOUD_PROJECT_DEV: "team4tress-dev"

dependencies:
  pre:
    - sudo chown -R $USER /home/ubuntu/.config
    # Download App Engine SDK
    # This is not necessary to deploy, its only necessary  to run local tests importing the App Engine SDK
    - curl -o $HOME/google_appengine_1.9.30.zip https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.30.zip
    - unzip -q -d $HOME $HOME/google_appengine_1.9.30.zip
    # Make sure gcloud is up to date
    - gcloud --quiet components update app
    - echo "y" | sudo /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud components update --version 146.0.0

test:
  override:

deployment:
  staging:
    branch: master
    commands:
      # Replace <your-project-id>
      - gcloud config set project $GCLOUD_PROJECT

      - sudo chown -R $USER /home/ubuntu/.config
      - echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
      - sudo /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
      - sudo /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config set project $GCLOUD_PROJECT


      # deploy to AppEngine
      - sudo chown -R $USER /home/ubuntu/.config/gcloud/credentials
      - gcloud -q app deploy app.yaml --promote

    development:
      branch: dev
      commands:

        # Replace <your-project-id>
        - gcloud config set project $GCLOUD_PROJECT_DEV

        - sudo chown -R $USER /home/ubuntu/.config
        - echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY_DEV | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
        - sudo /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
        - sudo /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config set project $GCLOUD_PROJECT_DEV


        # deploy to AppEngine
        - sudo chown -R $USER /home/ubuntu/.config/gcloud/credentials
        - gcloud -q app deploy app.yaml --promote
```

My problem is that when I push a change to my "dev" branch, the circle build runs, but stops right before the "deployment" section. When I push on master, it runs the deployment section as expected, but I can't seem to get the "dev" deployment part to trigger when I push on dev.

Here is my branch structure:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:fourtress alex$ git branch
  dev
* master
  staging
```

Any ideas why the deployment part is not running?

Comment: Hi, did you get to solve this after all? I am experiencing the same issue, though on AWS.